# How to deal with "Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action"

Tags: excel, vba, ole

When automating other MS-Office applications with excel, I frequently get ok-only prompts saying that `Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action.`

This only happens when automating lengthy tasks.

**How can I deal with this in an appropriate fashion?**

Two recent examples (I recon the code is less important):

- creating an accdb-Database from Excel with an `Access.Application` and populating it by running rather complex SQL-queries on large amount of data.

  ```
  Public Function createDB(pathDB As String, pathSQL As String) As String

      Dim dbs As DAO.Database
      Dim sql As String
      Dim statement As Variant, file As Variant

      Dim sErr As String, iErr As Integer

      With New Access.Application

          With .DBEngine.CreateDatabase(pathDB, dbLangGeneral)

              For Each file In Split(pathSQL, ";")

                  sql = fetchSQL(file)
                  For Each statement In Split(sql, ";" & vbNewLine)
                      If Len(statement) < 5 Then GoTo skpStatement
                      Debug.Print statement

                      On Error Resume Next
                      .Execute statement, dbFailOnError

                      With Err
                          If .Number <> 0 Then
                              iErr = iErr + 1
                              sErr = sErr & vbCrLf & "Error " & .Number & " | " & Replace(.Description, vbCrLf, vbNullString)
                              .Clear
                          End If
                      End With
                      On Error GoTo 0
  skpStatement:
                  Next statement
              Next file
          End With
          .Quit acQuitSaveAll
      End With

      dTime = Now() - starttime

      ' Returnwert
      If sErr = vbNullString Then sErr = "Keine Fehler"
      createDB = "Zeit: " & Now & " | Dauer: " & Format(dTime, "hh:mm:ss") & " | Anzahl Fehler: " & iErr & vbCrLf & sErr

      ' Log
      With ThisWorkbook
          '...
          .Saved = True
          .Save
      End With

  End Function
  ```
- create mail merges from Excel in a `Word.Application`, using existing and rather large `.docm`-templates and dynamic SQL-queries that returns the receipents

  ```
  Set rst = GetRecordset(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameter").Range("A1:S100"))

  With New Word.Application

      .Visible = False

      While Not rst.EOF
          If rst!Verarbeiten And Not IsNull(rst!Verarbeiten) Then
              Debug.Print rst!Sql

              .Documents.Open rst!inpath & Application.PathSeparator & rst!infile
              stroutfile = fCheckPath(rst!outpath, True) & Application.PathSeparator & rst!outfile

              .Run "quelle_aendern", rst!DataSource, rst!Sql

              .Run MacroName:="TemplateProject.AutoExec.SeriendruckInDokument"

              Application.DisplayAlerts = False

              .ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                  OutputFileName:=stroutfile _
                  , ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF _
                  , OpenAfterExport:=False _
                  , OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint _
                  , Range:=wdExportAllDocument _
                  , From:=1, To:=1 _
                  , Item:=wdExportDocumentContent _
                  , IncludeDocProps:=False _
                  , KeepIRM:=True _
                  , CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks _
                  , DocStructureTags:=False _
                  , BitmapMissingFonts:=True _
                  , UseISO19005_1:=False

              Application.DisplayAlerts = True

              For Each doc In .Documents
                  With doc
                      .Saved = True
                      .Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
                  End With
              Next doc

          End If
          rst.MoveNext
      Wend

      .Quit
  End With
  ```

**notes:**

- When run on a smaller scale (for example, when querying less records or using less complex templates), both codes do run smoothly.
- In both cases, when I `OK` through all the reappearing prompts, the code will eventually finish with the desired results.
  Therefore, I guess I'm not encountering an error (also it doesn't trigger the error handlers), but rather something like a timeout.

As suggested on other sources, I do wrap my code into `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`. This, however, seems like a horrible idea, since there might actually be cases where I do need to be alerted.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/microsoft.public.excel.programming/ct8NRT-o7rs/jawi42S8Ci0J

Comment: We need more context. How do the two methods relate? Does the mail merge connect to the database being built? Where do you call the two routines? It's not clear why you need to build a whole database on the fly each time.

Comment: Finally, it seems you have MS Access installed, consider using it to call the other office apps as it arguably has a better object model and application/automation environment.

Comment: Seems shutting off that message is tackling the *symptom* rather than the actual problem. If your queries have performance issues, the solution isn't to tell the client to stop whining - the solution is to get the queries to complete in a reasonable amount of time. Are you missing indexes? Are your queries written in inefficient ways? Anything that takes more than, say, 7 seconds to refresh, should be done differently. Consider doing the heavy processing overnight and dumping the results in a table, and then simply querying that table. Oh wait, Access. Good luck!

Comment: A little free code-review: Please consider changing `If Len(statement) < 5 Then GoTo skpStatement` to `if Len(statement) >=5 Then`. It eliminates the needless `GoTo` statement by simply testing for the cases when you _do_ want to execute the code instead of when you _don't_ want to.

Comment: @Mat'sMug `Oh wait, Access. Good luck!` Ye well, don't get me started. ;)
`SQL` runs as fast as you'd expect (no indexes bc flatfiles with `schema.ini`, normalizing columns to rows with `UNION ALL` for a lack of better options).... so: pretty slow. Still, I feel like I did what I could to streamline the `SQL`. I am perfectly content with the `.Execute` taking 10 minutes, as long as I am not buggered by messages suggesting something is amiss, when in fact the code does run error-free

Comment: @Parfait Thanks for your input. As stated, those are only two examples of lengthy operations that cause said behavior, not related. As for your 2nd point: interesting advice, will keep that in mind! Sadly, in this particular case, I had to use `Excel`, since afaik `Access` can't be automated with `Powershell`

Comment: @FreeMan Fair point, thanks for pointing that out. However, in that example, it's actually the `.Execute` that takes like 5 minutes per file (which by itself would be perfectly fine by me)

Comment: Eliminating the `Goto` has nothing to do with code execution speed (in particular), it's just an opportunity to get rid of a `Goto`! It's bad enough that we're forced to use them in VBA for error handling... :/ (Yes, there are a few legitimate uses for `Goto`, just not many.)

Comment: @MartinDreher I worked in a place where it was deemed *normal* for a SSRS report to take 30 minutes to process... People have varying standards I guess. Still, I would recommend you put your SQL up for review on [codereview.se] if you can - you never know, maybe there's a chance it can be tweaked to run in under 10 seconds =)

Comment: Yes, MSAccess.exe is an exe like Excel and so can be automated with PowerShell, Batch, Cmd, etc. Build a module called in its [AutoExec macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automate-startup-events-with-a-macro-b08d4f22-b517-4ccf-bd14-8670416628b0) so runs every time Access opens.

Comment: I am aware of Access being an exe. I do vaguely remember running into errors when powershell tried calling a sub that creates a database from scratch stored in my access database, with the same sub running smoothly when stored in an excel. Might want to look into it some more. **Thanks for your input guys!**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll add the code that @Tehscript linked to in the comments.

> You can solve this by using the COM API to remove VBA's message filter.
>   This will prevent COM from telling VBA to displaying a message box when it
>   thinks the process you're calling has blocked. Note that if the process
>   really has blocked for some reason this will prevent you from receiving any
>   notification of that.  [[source](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/microsoft.public.excel.programming/ct8NRT-o7rs/jawi42S8Ci0J)]

I think this is the code I used back in 2006 for the same problem (it worked).

```
Private Declare Function _
    CoRegisterMessageFilter Lib "OLE32.DLL" _
    (ByVal lFilterIn As Long, _
    ByRef lPreviousFilter) As Long

Sub KillMessageFilter()  
    '''Original script Rob Bovey  

    '''https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/microsoft.public.excel.programming/ct8NRT-o7rs/jawi42S8Ci0J
    '''http://www.appspro.com/

    Dim lMsgFilter As Long

    ''' Remove the message filter before calling Reflections.
    CoRegisterMessageFilter 0&, lMsgFilter

    ''' Call your code here....

    ''' Restore the message filter after calling Reflections.
    CoRegisterMessageFilter lMsgFilter, lMsgFilter

End Sub
```

Comment: @Tehscript , Darren: Does feel like I throwing the baby out with the bathwater. I do, however, really need that tub. Works for me, thanks a ton!

Comment: I add this issue while a mht file was locked by ms-word app instance fired up from ms-excel. Solution was to close the ms-word process, so that unlocking the mht file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the COM API code as well, which works. But it is only useful in so far as you don't see the error - the 30-sec delay every time the error is triggered still happens which makes this unworkable for me.

The better change I have made is to turn off "Real time presence in Microsoft Office" in Drive File Stream (the google product). This has (so far!) resolved the issue for me. I'm guessing there is some sort of clash between this and another excel addin.