# Ignore Popup "waiting for OLE action to finish"

Tags: excel

I wrote a couple scripts in VBA for Excel to interact with SAP.

Main issue is, at some point, a function in SAP is triggered that can take up to 10 minutes (thats normal).

The script works fine, but during the waiting for the process to finish, the SAP window isn't responsive and the script is stuck on that line (which is how i want it to work).
The issue I am having is, once SAP is done with its process, Excel has raised a popup which informs me that its waiting for an OLE action to finish, and as long as I do not click OK, it doesn't continue with the script.

How does one get around this?

Can I just disable this information in Excel or can I increase the time before this warning appears?

Comment: Have you tried: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`?

Comment: i havent tried that, but have found this solution, which works too
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50275308/17089022